# Does Python's reduce() short circuit?

Tags: python

If I do:

```
result = reduce(operator.and_, [False] * 1000)
```

Will it stop after the first result? (since `False & anything == False`)

Similarly:

```
result = reduce(operator.or_, [True] * 1000)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't. Your alternative in this case is [any](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) and [all](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all).

```
result = reduce(operator.and_, [False] * 1000)
result = reduce(operator.or_, [True] * 1000)
```

can be replaced by

```
result = all([False] * 1000)
result = any([True] * 1000)
```

which do short circuit.

The timing results show the difference:

```
In [1]: import operator

In [2]: timeit result = reduce(operator.and_, [False] * 1000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 113 us per loop

In [3]: timeit result = all([False] * 1000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.59 us per loop

In [4]: timeit result = reduce(operator.or_, [True] * 1000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 113 us per loop

In [5]: timeit result = any([True] * 1000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.49 us per loop
```

Comment: You're right. `any()` and `all()` seem to be exactly what I need (and probably clearer too). How did you do that timing?

Comment: I am using `ipython` and its `timeit` command. But Python has a timeit module. So you can do `python -mtimeit "result = any([True] * 10)"` from the command line for timing.

Answer (score 5):

Not only does reduce() not short-circuit, it cannot possibly short-circuit over all the items being reduced, because it only considers the items two at a time. Additionally, it has no idea of the conditions under which the function being used short-circuits. (It would be sorta nifty if functions could have a property that indicates the value at which they begin to short-circuit, which reduce() could then recognize and use, but they don't.)

Comment: This is why Lisp users love Lisp so much- because all functions are data, it's (in principal) possible to do this kind of detection.

Answer (score 3):

It may well be possible (see [fate of reduce](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)) that an alternative *reduce* implementation will do a good job.

This idea has perfectly worked for me to make things more transparent in the design.

```
def ipairs(seq):
    prev = None
    for item in seq:
        if prev is not None:
            yield (prev, item)
        prev = item

def iapply(seq, func):
    for a, b in ipairs(seq):
        yield func(a, b)

def satisfy(seq, cond):
    return all(iapply(seq, cond))

def is_uniform(seq):
    return satisfy(seq, lambda a, b: a == b)
```

As you see *reduce* is broken into  *iapply* <- *ipairs*.

Please note it is not equivalent to

```
def ireduce(seq, func):
    prev = None
    for item in seq:
        if prev is None:
            prev = item
        else:
            prev = func(prev, item)
    return prev
```

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that short circuit evaluation is not always what you want. "Fixing" reduce to short circuit would be a mistake for that reason. For example, I recently had to change my use of all() to reduce() while processing a list of forms in django: I want to report any is_valid() problems, not just the first one.

Comment: it could use a keyword argument for the short-circuit criteria, other builtins do : reduce (operator.or, mylist, key=lambda x : :x < 0)

Answer (score 1):

I had a related use case where I wanted a behavior different from `any` and `all` but equivalent to a loop over `or` and `and`. The solution is to use `filter` rather than `reduce`.

`any` returns booleans while `or` returns the last object evaluated as `True`.

```
>>> any(['', 'a'])
True
>>> any(['', ''])
False
>>> any([0, 1])
True
>>> any([0, 0])
False
```

`or` returns the last object evaluated as `True`.

```
>>> '' or 'a'
'a'
>>> '' or ''
''
>>> 0 or 1
1
>>> 0 or 0
0
```

`reduce(operator.or_, xs)` will not short circuit but `next(filter(bool, xs))` in python3 or `next(itertools.ifilter(bool, xs))` in python2 will short circuit. It is not because `filter` short circuits, but because iterator returned is lazy and will only evaluate when needed. By using `next` we are only asking for first element that satisfies the filter criteria.

```
>>> def maybenext(iter, onstopiter=False):
...     try: return  next(iter)
...     except StopIteration: return onstopiter
...     
>>> 
>>> maybenext(filter(bool, ['', 'a']))
'a'
>>> maybenext(filter(bool, ['', '']))
False
>>> maybenext(filter(bool, [0, 1]))
1
>>> maybenext(filter(bool, [0, 0]))
False
```

The result is not as fast as `any` but close enough

```
>>> %timeit maybenext(filter(bool, [1] * 1000))
2.48 µs ± 91.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit any([1] * 1000)
2.26 µs ± 90.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit reduce(operator.or_, [1] * 1000)
47.3 µs ± 1.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible lazy reduce implementation:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def lazy_reduce(pred, reducer, it, initial=None):
    accum = accumulate(it, reducer, initial=initial)
    last = None
    for item in accum:
        last = item
        if pred(item):
            return item
    return last
```

This should work like reduce but will short on `pred`.

```
from operator import add
from itertools import count
res = short_reduce(lambda x: x > 20, add, count(1,8)) # 27
```