# What is the most 'pythonic' way to logically combine a list of booleans?

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have a list of booleans I'd like to logically combine using and/or.  The expanded operations would be:

```
vals = [True, False, True, True, True, False]

# And-ing them together
result = True
for item in vals:
    result = result and item

# Or-ing them together
result = False
for item in vals:
    result = result or item
```

Are there nifty one-liners for each of the above?

Comment: Related, though not obvious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570624/does-pythons-reduce-short-circuit

Answer (score 128, accepted):

See [`all(iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) :

> Return `True` if all elements of the
>   *iterable* are true (or if the *iterable*
>   is empty).

And [`any(iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) :

> Return `True` if any element of the
>   *iterable* is true. If the *iterable* is empty, return `False`.

Answer (score 15):

The best way to do it is with the `any()` and `all()` functions.

```
vals = [True, False, True, True, True]
if any(vals):
   print "any() reckons there's something true in the list."
if all(vals):
   print "all() reckons there's no non-True values in the list."
if any(x % 4 for x in range(100)):
   print "One of the numbers between 0 and 99 is divisible by 4."
```

Comment: My boolean list is generated by a list comprehension on another list.  Now I can wrap them all together.  Nice!

Comment: Okay, if that's the case, you can make it a generator expression: